# How to pass the self object to the trace.Trace.run() method?

Tags: python, trace

In order to trace the execution of a program (exactly I want to follow the modules / classes / methods used when executing a particular line in a code), I try to use the [trace module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#module-trace).

The line I want to explore is this:

`trait = self._trait(name, 0)`

so I changed this line in the code to:

`#trait = self._trait(name, 0)
import trace
tracer = trace.trace(count=False, trace=True)
tracer.run('trait = self._trait(name, 0)')`

The problem is that in this case an exception is raised because self is not defined (since we pass a string in the tracer.run() ! method).

`File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/trace.py", line 462, in runctx
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name "self' is not defined`

Is it possible to pass an object (as self) to the tracer.trace.run() method ?

Is there another way more suitable for this case to explore the path made during a python command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the context for running the python statement to be traced using the `runctx` method. Here's an example, that says to put `self` into the tracer context as a local variable so that it can be referenced there:

```
import trace

class A:
  def f(self):
      self.g()
      print('f')

  def g(self):
      print('g')

  def h(self):
      # trace self.f()
      tracer = trace.Trace(count=False, trace=True)
      # define a local variable in the context named 'self'
      tracer.runctx('self.f()', locals={'self': self})

a = A()
a.h()
```

The output:

```
 --- modulename: trc, funcname: f
trc.py(5):       self.g()
 --- modulename: trc, funcname: g
trc.py(9):       print('g')
g
trc.py(6):       print('f')
f
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(77):         sys.settrace(None)
```

Comment: Exactly what i looked for ! Cool :-)